# Health science researcher(s) or health sciences researcher(s)

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

As the title reveals, what is the correct usage:

> 1) "Health science researchers" or "health sciences researchers"?

Similarly:

> 2) "Researchers in health science" or "researchers in the health sciences"?

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted; I think it's a fair question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically faculties and institutions are attached to health sciences, while degrees are in a singular health science.

Ex:

> - Faculty of Health Sciences
> - Bachelor of Health Science

Unless all the researchers being discussed in the paragraph belong to the same health science (immunology for instance), option D ("researchers in the health sciences") is the least ambiguous, especially if this is a generic statement as part of an introduction.